Is the group law on a conic an instance of something more general?
As described e.g. here, a group law can be defined on an arbitrary conic $C$ by fixing a point $N \in C$ and defining the sum of two points $P, Q \in C$ to be the (other) point of intersection between $C$ and the line parallel to $PQ$ that passes through $N$, like so:

Is this group law an isolated phenomenon, or is it an instance of something more general?  In asking this question, I have in mind the case of the group law on an elliptic curve, which is "really" the group law on the Picard group of the curve, transported to the curve by the (in the case of elliptic curves) bijective correspondence between (equivalence classes of) linear divisors and points on the curve (it can't be the same story here, since the group law here is only defined on the affine points).

The reducible cubic $z(x^2+y^2-z^2)=0$ in ${\Bbb P}^2$ with the usual group law as for smooth cubics with a rational point (an elliptic curve) reduce to this one, the third point on a line always being at infinity.

@Jan-MagnusØkland that's very nice! If you'd like to post that as an answer, even just as it is, I'd very happily select it.

Consider the reducible cubic $z\cdot (x^2+y^2-z^2)=0$ in ${\Bbb P}^2.$ Avoid the circular points at infinity, and try the usual group law as for smooth cubics with a rational point (elliptic curves).
Then the third point on the lines is always on the line at infinity $z=0,$ giving the direction for parallel lines and your group law for the circle wrt the point $N$ is recovered.
